# Pause property changed event while typing in Xceed decimal up down control

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, xceed

I have decimal up control in my wpf application. While I am trying to 0.5. When I am type 0 in decinmal up down text box. It will raise property changed event. In that property changed.

My requirement was to raise property change event when I am finish typing.

This decimal up control used lot of places in my application. How to write code in (generic way/ single place) to resolve that issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every Binding has the Property "UpdateSourceTrigger".
I would try to set that value to "LostFocus" so PropertyChanged should only be invoked when the control looses focus.

```
{Binding value, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}
```

A good explanation of UpdateSourceTrigger is at: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/507883/UpdateSourceTrigger-Property-in-WPF-Binding